# How to change tabs programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Im using http://www.menucool.com/tabbed-content to make tabs.
 Is there any way to change tabs by `jquery/javascript` ? i have tried `$("tab1").click();`

Created a fiddle for this-
https://jsfiddle.net/6e3y9663/1/

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far? Put it on fiddle. I know how tabs works and I can help you.

Comment: I'm assuming tab1 is the id. If that's the case you are missing #: $("#tab1").click();

Comment: @Herm Luna  i have created a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/6e3y9663/1/

Comment: @HermLuna    https://jsfiddle.net/6e3y9663/1/

Comment: @user6708151 your tabs is working fine. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @HermLuna im trying to change tabs through javascript. I want to open the first tab through code.

Answer (score 1):

Play with the selected class

```
$('.tabs').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');//reset the tab buttons
$('#desiredTab').parent().addClass('selected');//or $('li a[href="#tab1"]').parent().addClass('selected'); - select the desired tab header
id = $('#desiredTab').attr('href');
$(id).siblings().hide();//reset the tab content
$(id).show();//$('#tab1').show();  -show the desired tab content
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/6e3y9663/5/

Comment: will just adding selected class also display the tab content or just change the tab bar? Using the id selector to add class doesnt work.

Comment: you need to mach the tab button with its content for the tab button you add the selected class for the content you have to have a display block added to it(show the contnet)

Comment: its not working, i have created a fiddle for this . Hope this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/6e3y9663/1/